# Application settings appear after clean when program copied elsewhere

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, build, application-settings

I have a `WinForm` project with one form and an application settings file. When the form loads, it reads from application settings and if the program successfully runs (i.e. the file is written to the destination) the application settings are saved for the next runs.

I am noticing a strange behavior as I build my solution:

When I clean and rebuild my solution and test my program in the `bin/Release` folder, everything looks fine and the application settings are clear. But when I copy the same files to another destination and run the program from there (even though the `.exe.config` file is also replaced with the new clean version) it seems that the copy version still remembers my application settings. What could possibly cause this?

Comment: I used to have this problem with my Windows Service. VS seemed to cache an old version somehow. What helped me was to create a new project altogether.

Comment: @avantvous I see! And what is the guarantee that the new project is not behaved the same way by Visual Studio?

Comment: No guarantee, but it worked for me every time. Give it a try, but still keep the old copy just in case.

Comment: @avantvous but it will work fine when run from another computer, right?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yes and the default values inside the `.exe.config` file are now empty.

Comment: For me that wasn't the case, unfortunately.

Comment: @avantvous you mentioned "*VS seemed to cache an old version somehow.*" So where is that cache stored that does not affect the version in `bin/Release` but the version that is copied elsewhere?

Comment: If only I knew that, I wouldn't have to create a new project but just delete the cache ;)

Comment: @RezaAghaei You are right! It got resolved when I cleared the cache from my `AppData/Local`. You can post the answer if you like!

Comment: @Disasterkid I edited the answer. The answer is now more accurate and contains new facts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Settings.Settings` in a normal way, considering these facts will help you to have a better understanding about user settings:

- When you save settings using `Properties.Default.Settings.Save()` current values for user settings are stored in `%userprofile%\appdata\local` in a folder with the name of your application in a sub folder which is unique for deployment.
- Each deployment has a unique path, so when you copy your application in a previously used path, it assumed as an update to your previous deployment and your previous user setting will be remembered and merged with new added settings.
- If you copy the application in a totally new path, it assumed as a new deployment and your previous user settings will not be remembered.
- Only the default values are stored in `.config` file beside `.exe` of your application, so deleting them has no impact on remembering the user saved values.