# Synchronize button in WinForms "Settings" Designer is looking for user.config in the wrong "Url" location

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, settings

I'm trying to reset my user settings for debugging purposes. I'm using the "Synchronize" button under the Settings area of the Project designer. When I do so, I get a message box with the following:

> No user.config files were found in any of the following locations:
>
> C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\MyCompanyName\Job_Dashboard.exe_Url_cxdbq4we0vujxxk3deh2qr2dq3i5kz5m\1.1._
>
> C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\MyCompanyName\Job_Dashboard.exe_Url_cxdbq4we0vujxxk3deh2qr2dq3i5kz5m\1.1._
>
> C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\MyCompanyName\Job_Dashboard.exe_Url_24oqbm3g45gfzsxxv5olluxp4sstx5rd\1.1._
>
> C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\MyCompanyName\Job_Dashboard.exe_Url_24oqbm3g45gfzsxxv5olluxp4sstx5rd\1.1._

After some investigating, I determined without a doubt that my debug session user.config file is actually being saved at this location:

> C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\MyCompanyName\Job_Dashboard.exe_Url_x1qpbuzhilhu1j1pt1g1iysdnoghdcey

This is the only folder under my `AppData\Local\MyCompanyName` folder, and there are NO folders under my `AppData\Roaming\MyCompanyName` folder. This folder also corresponds to and updates with any settings changes I make while debugging my application. So it's clearly the correct folder.

However, that folder has a completely different "Url" ID from either of the Local folders the Settings designer is looking for when doing a Synchronize... which explains why it can't find it.

Why is it looking for the wrong folder, and how do I correct this?

I found some threads recommending to delete my company folder under the AppData\Local folder, rebuild my project, and run it to re-create the settings folder. I did this, but it just re-creates it under the same Url, and Synchronize continues looking for the same incorrect Urls.

Comment: Looks like a bug in visual studio

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35864728/3110834